# Why I can't retrieve scopes into token with oauth for Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, guzzle

I want to use the Microsoft Graph API on my application (which is actually on development).

I use fullcalendar js on my application (laravel 8) and when a user create an event on my application I want the same event create on his outlook calendar.

I want that the user connected on my application has only the right to access his outlook calendar (not all organization users calendar). In order to restrict this I understand that I have to use delegated autorizations and not applications autorizations.

First I would like to get an access token in order to use the API.
To do this I use oauth2 and guzzle :

```php
        $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . env('MS_TENANT_ID'). '/oauth2/v2.0/token?api-version=1.0';

        $tokenCall = Http::asForm()->post($url, [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'client_id' => env('MS_CLIENT_ID'),
            'client_secret' => env('MS_CLIENT_SECRET'),
            'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
            'username' => 'xxx.xxx@xxx.com',
            'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
        ]);

        $accessToken = json_decode($tokenCall->getBody()->getContents());
```

I obtain a token but when I inspect it with jwt.io, it appears that I haven't scopes in it (scp).

Do you know why it doesn't appears?

EDIT:
It appears that I use an application authentication and not a delegated authentication (for user).

So I change the 'grant_type' parameters for 'password' instead of 'client_credentials'.

But it throws me another error :

```
invalid_grant
AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' named 'Graph PHP'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
```

I read that in an delegated authentication I have to call the authorize point before the token point.

To do this I have to define a Redirect URI on my application on Azure. Unfortunately I made development on a local server (not localhost) which haven't SSL. Azure dosen't allow the Redirect URI to be on http except for localhost...

Is someone have already face this problem?

Comment: `'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'` would get you a client token, that can be used to make requests on behalf of your app. I don't think that is what you want, actually? If you want to perform actions in the name of an individual user, then you need to get a user access token.

Comment: Thanks @Broe, so I understand that I have to change grant_type for 'password' and not 'client_credentials'. But when I change it it throws me this error : "invalid_grant AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' named 'Graph PHP'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource." I think that if I obtain a token with client_credentials but not with password , there is a link with user authorizations (not application) maybe?

Comment: @Petitemo If you need a user authorized token, you should probably use the auth code grant - which requires user interaction in a browser an the user may give a consent to your application performing actions on the user's behalf (using an access token).

Comment: @JánHalaša Ok I understand but do you know if I can obtain this without the user interaction in the browser? It's for an internal application for commercials and it will be a shame if they have to accept it at each creation of an event... Or can I add to my authentication form an input for this consent?

Comment: @Petitemo Users will probably have to give a consent only once. You can also keep a refresh token during its validity period (and use it to generate access tokens), so it's not necessary for users to go to the OAuth2 server for your application to get new tokens. But if you don't need a user (just your client service account), try removing the username and password from the request.

Comment: Ok @JánHalaša if a refresh token is available I can ask for user consent. So I try some api request with authorize endpoint. But I'm facing another problem. I made another question because it's a different issue = [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75522414/how-can-i-get-azure-auth-code-grant-error-50058)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some sample for OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant type, or auth code flow, enables a client application to obtain authorized access to protected resources like web APIs.

```
// Line breaks for legibility only

POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&grant_type=authorization_code
&code_verifier=ThisIsntRandomButItNeedsToBe43CharactersLong 
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh    // NOTE: Only required for web apps. This secret needs to be URL-Encoded.
```

For reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token-with-a-client_secret