# How can I get Azure auth code grant (error 50058)

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, laravel-8

I'm searching how getting an auth grant code for my web application.

I'm using laravel 8 for my application.

I'm facing a problem when I try to authenticate with the authorize endpoint of Microsoft Azure.

When I run this request :

```php
return Http::get('https://login.microsoftonline.com/34ad407a....4aa02a/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=1c86c0f...43e0c
&response_type=code
&approval_prompt=auto&
&redirect_uri=https://xx.com
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/User.read
&state=12345');
```

The Microsoft Sign In box right appears.

But when I want to enter my email account and click on next it throws me this error :
`There was an issue looking up your account. Tap Next to try again.`

I can see that the error code is 50058
So I check it on https://login.microsoftonline.com/error :

```
Error code : 50058
Message : Session information is not sufficient for single-sign-on.
Remediation : This means that a user is not signed in. 
This is a common error that's expected when a user is unauthenticated and has not yet signed in. 
If this error is encountered in an SSO context where the user has previously signed in, this means that the SSO session was either not found or invalid. 
This error may be returned to the application if prompt=none is specified.
```

Do you have any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: There will be probably more issues but scope should be `scope=user.read` not `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/User.read`. Get rid of `&approval_prompt=auto&`

Comment: Using `return Http::get()` is totally wrong here. You need to redirect the user to the login URL _in their browser_, not try to make that request from the server side.